# C# locking - Global Static Variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, thread-safety

In my Global.cs, there is a public static dictionary variable name "DataDict". I'm trying to set some data into dictionary object after 'Post Authentication' method in the global.cs and use it in one of the controller/api classes. I'm trying to prevent corrupting of the data in the multi threaded environment. Coded like sample #1. My question is, can i just use the approach #2? It would be thread safe and data wont be corrupted (or) no locking issues. Thinking #1 is more safer?

//Sample # 1

```
if (Global.DataDict !=null && Global.DataDict.Count > 0)
    {
       lock (lockObj)
        {
           if (Global.DataDict !=null && Global.DataDict.Count > 0)
          {
                var key = GetKeyInfo();
                var data = Global.DataDict[key];
           }
        }
    }
```

//Sample - 2

```
if (Global.DataDict !=null && Global.DataDict.Count > 0)
{
  lock (lockObj)
    {
    var key = GetKeyInfo();
    var data = Global.DataDict[key];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a concurrent dictionary?

Comment: General Knowledge recommends you read the following article
[safe thread](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx)

Comment: @maccettura: will use that. Thank you.